# Animating UInavigationBar offscreen leaves black rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to the UINavigationBar onto screen when a modal UIView appears, as it does in Reeder.

I'm using the excellent SVWebViewController (https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) to handle creating a web browser from a shouldStartLoadWithRequest

The animation code is from http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/06/02/iphone-app-animation-tutorial-animate-a-uiview-frame/

Everything works as in the navigationbar is placed off screen but the space left behind (that I want to animate it into it) is BLACK. The rest of the view/webview is WHITE.

How can I make the space allocated to navbar white, ie the background of the view white?
There is no xib.

I can't find any mention of the navbar in SVWebViewController (only adding a toolbar)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"They clicked: %@", request);

    NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];

    if ([[requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http"] || [[requestURL scheme] isEqualToString: @"https"]) {


            NSLog(@"Web link %@",requestURL);

            SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:requestURL];
            webViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

            webViewController.availableActions = SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsOpenInSafari | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsCopyLink | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsMailLink;

            // ios5

            if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {

                // Create image for navigation background - portrait
                UIImage *NavigationPortraitBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg_portrait~iPad"]
                                                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

                // Create image for navigation background - landscape
                UIImage *NavigationLandscapeBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg_portrait~iPad"]
                                                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

                // Set the background image all UINavigationBars
                [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
                [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationLandscapeBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

                [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

                // The tintcolor affects the button colour
                UIColor* col = OPAQUE_HEXCOLOR(0xdb536a);
                [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:col];

            } else {

                // Style the Nav Bar ios4
                [webViewController.navigationBar applyCustomTintColor];

            }
            [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];


            // -> This code hides the UINavigationBar before animation

            CGRect navBarFrame = webViewController.navigationBar.frame;

            navBarFrame.origin.y = -navBarFrame.size.height;

            // set the position of the bar
            webViewController.navigationBar.frame = navBarFrame;

            // <- end Hide code


            return NO;

        }

    return YES;
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to change the colour of the the area left behind if you animate a UINavigationBar is

self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the NavBar offscreen, nothing is currently left in this spot, that's why it's black.
You should try to enlarge the WebView to fill up the space the NavBar previously covered by adjusting it's frame property.

Comment: By setting the uiwebview masks? And if so what are the settings pleases (I'm a xib fanboy!)

Comment: I'm not using a xib... here's the init code - (void)loadView {
    mainWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    
    [mainWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    
    
    mainWebView.delegate = self;
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [mainWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URL]];
    self.view = mainWebView;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your nib file for the Controller and the Web View, set the auto resize mask on the Web View to automatically resize height and width. Then it'll work.

Comment: As I mentioned the class has no xib